# how to enable host pc as router using slaac concept without radvd

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, ipv6, slaac

We setup a IPv6 network with two ubuntu systems and we make one PC as HOST and other as ROUTER(based on the concept of SLAAC). The host sent the "Router solicitation" message, but the router pc not respond with any "Router advertisement".
router pc is configured as

> sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.enp1s0.autoconf=1
>
> sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.enp1s0.accept_ra=2
>
> sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.enp1s0.forwarding=1

Can you please suggest any solution?

Answer (score 1):

> How to run a router without installing the correct software?

The answer is: you can't…

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel alone has no built-in support for sending ICMPv6 Router Advertisements, neither solicited nor periodically (you need both).

You *will* need some additional software capable of doing so, e.g.:

- radvd
- BIRD Routing Daemon
- systemd-networkd

Comment: what are the configuration required in  systemd-networkd for SLAAC operation

Comment: See the `[IPv6Prefix]` section in _systemd.network(5)_.